# Comparar TextBox com campo em uma tabela SQLServer

Tags: c#

Estou travado nesse **if**. Quero comparar meu **textbox** com um campo em uma tabela no **sql server**, porem não sei como continuar.

segue o código:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{               

string queryString = "SELECT id, nome, cpf FROM " + GetType().Name + "s";

SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

comand.Connection.Open();

comand.ExecuteNonQuery();

****GOSTARIA de verificar se já existe esse usuário cadastrado no banco de dados****

      if (reader.Read())
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]) == txtCodigo.Text)//essa condição é verdadeira, deveria executar este if, porem, cai direto no else
                {
                    AtualizarCadastro();
                }
                else
                {
                    Gravar();

                }
            } 
}
```

Obrigado desde já!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente desta maneira:

```
 SqlDataReader reader = comand.ExecuteReader(); //Executa o leitor
 if (reader.read())
 {
     if (txtCodigo.Text == reader[0].ToString()) //[0] é a primeira coluna que o select irá retornar, no seu caso o "id".
     {
      MessageBox.Show("Este usuário já foi cadastrado no banco de dados!"); //Só para testar.
     }
 }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Retornou este erro ao incluir a alteração sugerida:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Tentativa inválida de leitura quando não existem dados."

Estou pesquisando sobre.

Comment: Está retornando este erro somente quando o if é false ou em qualquer caso?

Comment: Em qualquer caso.

Comment: Tente adicionar um `if (reader.read())` em volta da condição. Editei a resposta, para que não haja dúvidas.

Comment: Ele até leu e entrou no if, porem estou testando com o codigo "id" igual ao da minha tabela do banco de dados, e depurando no Visual Studio, está caindo no else... Isso que eu não estou entendendo, parece que não está armazenando a informação que vem do DB no Reader...vou editar a pergunta com o if//else pra vc ver, de

Comment: Teste os valores que estão retornando. Exemplo: `MessageBox.Show(id + 
"\n"  + reader[0].ToString());`

Comment: Pode me dizer qual era o problema e como consertou?

Comment: O reader[0], estava certo, lendo o primeiro registro... só que não era isso que eu queria, o certo era ler o registro selecionado em um datagridview, minha lógica que estava falha... Armazenei o ID selecionado no datagridview em uma propriedade dentro de uma classe no meu projeto, ai resolveu o problema.